# Probability of getting 3 blue skittles in even-sized allotments from the same bag

Tags: probability

Let's say Skittles come in 3 colors: red, green, and blue. If I pour a bag of 90 Skittles into 10 bowls of 9 Skittles each, the probability of getting >= 3 blue Skittles in any bowl is 1/3. Is the probability of getting >= 3 blue Skittles in all 10 bowls *also* 1/3?

I would think the probability of all bowls having >= 3 blue Skittles decreases with every additional bowl because of random variance: eg how is the all-bowl probability affected if 1 bowl has, say, 5/9 blue Skittles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of getting at least $3$ blue skittles in a bowl is $$
1-\sum_{k=0}^2\frac{\binom{30}{k}\binom{60}{9-k}}{\binom{90}{9}}\approx.632509$$  There are $\binom{30}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ blue skittles, $\binom{60}{9-k}$ ways to choose $9-k$ non-blue skittles, and $\binom{90}{9}$ ways to choose $9$ skittles, so the fraction gives the probability of getting exactly $k$ blue skittles.  The probability of getting at least $3$ blue skittles is the same as the probability of *not* getting $0,\ 1,$ or $2$.

The number of ways to put $3$ blue skittles in each bowl is $$\frac{30!}{(3!)^{10}}\approx$$ because we can line the skittles up in $30!$ ways, put the first $3$ in the first bowl, the next $3$ in the second bowl, and so on.  However, the order in which the skittles go into the bowl doesn't matter, so we have to divide by $3!$ in each case.  Similarly, there are $$\frac{60!}{(6!)^{10}}$$ ways to put $6$ non-blue skittles in each bowl, and $$\frac{90!}{(9!)^{10}}$$ ways to put $9$ skittles in each bowl, so the probability that there are $3$ blue skittles in each bowl is $$\frac{\binom{9}{3}^{10}}{\binom{90}{30}}\approx.00002598$$

I don't understand the last part.  If one of the bowls has $5$ skittles, then the probability of having $3$ skittles in each bowl is $0$.

Comment: I realize my question lacks a critical detail. I'm looking for the prob that one and all bowls contain __at least__ 3 blue Skittles. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @slider Each bowl contains at least $3$ blue skittles if and only if each bowl contains exactly $3$ blue skittles.

Comment: Precisely. How would we solve for that probability?

Comment: @slider I already did that in the answer.

Comment: I computed the probability for at least $3$ blues skittles in WolframAlpha, $63%$ seems awfully high.  I'm doing some checking.  Nope, it's right.